# Building a function to increment months with years with While Loop & Momentjs

Tags: javascript, while-loop, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I am trying to build a function that will allow me to increment `x` amount of months from the current month. I am using `while loop` and `momentjs` I am able to increment the months, but having troubles incrementing the years properly. Here's the code:

```
const generateMonths = (count) => {

let
  date = new Date(),
  month = date.getMonth(),
  year = date.getFullYear(),
  months = 12 + count,
  result = [];

while (month < months) {

 if (month >= 12) {
    let nextYear = year + 1;
    result.push(moment().month(month++).format("MMMM") + ' ' + nextYear);
  } else {
    result.push(moment().month(month++).format("MMMM") + ' - ' + year);
    }
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(generateMonths(24));
```

The  result I am getting:

`["August - 2016", "September - 2016", "October - 2016", "November - 2016", "December - 2016", "January 2017", "February 2017", "March 2017", "April 2017", "May 2017", "June 2017", "July 2017", "August 2017", "September 2017", "October 2017", "November 2017", "December 2017", "January 2017", "February 2017", "March 2017", "April 2017", "May 2017", "June 2017", "July 2017", "August 2017", "September 2017", "October 2017", "November 2017", "December 2017"]`

The year is stuck at `2017` since the increment happens only once, what is the proper way of doing it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you try `let nextYear = year++;`?

Comment: It looks like you're already aware that the issue is `nextYear` only incrementing once. Why not define `let nextYear = year` outside of your `if(month >= 12)` but inside the `while(month < months)` and inside of `if(month >= 12)` you can do `nextYear++`

Comment: ["August - 2016", "September - 2016", "October - 2016", "November - 2016", "December - 2016", "January 2016", "February 2017", "March 2018", "April 2019", "May 2020", "June 2021", "July 2022", "August 2023", "September 2024", "October 2025", "November 2026", "December 2027", "January 2028", "February 2029", "March 2030", "April 2031", "May 2032", "June 2033", "July 2034", "August 2035", "September 2036", "October 2037", "November 2038", "December 2039"]

Comment: @Hodrobond same result as the function i have now

Comment: You may wish to also create a temporary variable for your months. Whenever you get to a new year you're not resetting the months to 0, and because it remains >12 the year will repeatedly get incremented =)

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code to make it work as expected. Note that the variable `month` continues to increase by 1 even after 12, and so the difference between the first year and the new year can be calculating by dividing `month` by 12 and taking the integer part of that result.

```js
const generateMonths = (count) => {

let
  date = new Date(),
  month = date.getMonth(),
  year = date.getFullYear(),
  months = 12 + count,
  result = [];

while (month < months) {

    let newYear = Math.floor(month / 12) + year;
    result.push(moment().month(month++).format("MMMM") + ' ' + newYear);
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(generateMonths(24));
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works great! could you explain how it works? Math.floor rounds a number month / 12 = 0.something? .. I didn't fully understand how it works Thanks

Comment: @JasonBrill I added some more text. `month / 12` is not always less than one, because `month` keeps increasing and is not set back to 1 after the 12th month.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using moment, you can use [`add`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) method and simplyfy your code.

**EDIT**:
I've used `while` instead of `for` to fix results after [Ilan Hasanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6306298/ilan-hasanov) comment.

Here a working example:

```js
const generateMonths = (count) => {

let
  date = moment(),
  month = date.month(),
  months = 12 + count,
  result = [];

  while (month < months) {
    result.push( date.format("MMMM YYYY") );
    date.add(1 ,'month');
    month++;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(generateMonths(24));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Very nice. I like this better than my solution.

Comment: This will generate 36 months instead of 24 :) @VincenzoC